# How to merge changes from one branch to another in git

Tags: git

I am new to GIT, so please bear with my technical terms related to GIT.

Steps:
a. I created a new branch (Y) on the remote server from base branch (X) and then checked out the same on my local machine.

b. I did few changes in 'Y' on my local.

c. Someone has created a new branch (Z) on the remote server from 'X'.

**Q) Now, I want to copy all changes from Z to Y, both on local and remote, how do I do that? Also, need to make sure that my changes done in Y are not lost.**

Please elaborate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do `git fetch {repository} Z` from remote to local [REM] to [LOC]

Then do `git branch Z` [LOC]

Then do `git checkout Z` [LOC]

And after that you've got to merge the `FETCH_HEAD` [LOC]

`git merge FETCH_HEAD` [LOC]

Then switch to branch `Y` in your local. [LOC]

And do `git merge Y` [LOC]

The above process can be inscribed in words as follows:

You download the newly created branch from your remote repository to your local repository using 'git fetch', this allows you to have your branch/repo downloaded to your local repo, but without any further operation such as merging. It is just kept apart in pseudo-branch called `FETCH_HEAD`. You then create a branch in your local, merge the content of of `FETCH_HEAD` (which in your case is branch Z of remote repository. Now you have a separated branch containing the latest changes made through branch Z of remote repo. In the end, you merge the content of your new local branch into whatever branch you like.